# How can I select all fields except for those with non-distinct values?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which represents data for people that have applied. Each person has one PERSON_ID, but can have multiple APP_IDs. I want to select all of the columns except for APP_ID(because its values aren't distinct) for all of the distinct **people** in the table.

I can list every field individually in both the select and group by clause

This works:

```
select PERSON_ID, FIRST,LAST,MIDDLE,BIRTHDATE,SEX,EMAIL,PRIMARY_PHONE from 
applications
where first = 'Rob' and last='Robot'
group by PERSON_ID,FIRST,LAST,MIDDLE,BIRTHDATE,SEX,EMAIL,PRIMARY_PHONE
```

But there are twenty more fields that I may or may not use at any given time

Is there any shorter way to achieve this sort of selection without being so verbose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select distinct` is shorter:

```
select distinct PERSON_ID, FIRST, LAST, MIDDLE, BIRTHDATE, SEX, EMAIL, PRIMARY_PHONE 
from applications
where first = 'Rob' and last = 'Robot';
```

But you still have to list out the columns once.

Some more modern databases support an `except` clause that lets you remove columns from the wildcard list.  To the best of my knowledge, Oracle has no similar concept.

You could write a query to bring the columns together from the system tables.  That could simplify writing the query and help prevent misspellings.